# Installing windows 7 setup.exe in a new hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have an old hard drive which has my files in it and it still has an OS but now i have a new pc and i'm planning to switch to that old hard drive and install a new OS from there. I have a windows 7 installer but i think its not .ISO and has only a setup. exe

I don't want to boot the old hard drive to my new pc cause i heard that isn't recommended.

Comment: You need to make it an .iso I also have never heard of a setup.exe for Windows you sure it's what you think it is?

Comment: @Ramhound Well i borrowed my friend's hard drive and she said they have windows 7 and i saw a folder of win7 and saw a setup.exe. I opened it and it has "check compatibility" and "install now".

Comment: Do you have a Windows 7 license.  There are better ways to install Windows 7 like using official .iso files from Microsoft's digital partner Digital River

Answer (score 0):

Try Universal USB installer from Ubuntu's site. It has an option for windows too.
Point to your old hard disk (make sure you check the "show system drives" option).
Make a zip of your setup.
Change its extension to .iso.
Select the .iso file and just select install..
Now boot from your old hard drive.. Voila ! Windows Setup starts :-)